# get dynamic properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, properties

```
var tinymce_toolbar = {}
tinymce_toolbar.__default =
{
   script_url: '/cms/libs/js/manual/renders/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',  
};
tinymce_toolbar.__simple =
{
   script_url: '/cms/libs/js/manual/renders/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_simple.js',   
};


// Doesn't work
var t = $(this).find('input[name=toolbar]').first().val();
$('.RenderHtmlEditor').tinymce(tinymce_toolbar.t);

// works
var t = $(document).find('input[name=toolbar]').first().val();
$('.RenderHtmlEditor').tinymce(tinymce_toolbar.__default);
$('.RenderHtmlEditor').tinymce(tinymce_toolbar.__simple);
```

how i do it to be dynamic? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`object['name']` is quite same way as `object.name`. simply assign a associative attribute and use it as a property.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of dot notation,

```
tinymce_toolbar.t
```

Use [subscript notation](http://alexander.kirk.at/2006/03/02/a-better-understanding-of-javascript/):

```
tinymce_toolbar[t]
```